# Twitter sharing with Twitter app and returning to my app

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

Is it possible to post a message to twitter using twitter app installed on device and automatically get back to my app? I can open twitter app with

```
  NSURL* myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://post?message=%@", sharingString]];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myUrl];
```

but after that there is no way to automatically get back.

For Facebook there is a nice way to do it with the FBConnect and FBAuth, is there anything similar for twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the new `TWTweetComposeViewController` that comes with the iOS 5 SDK?